# Extract Files from Java project, during run proccess

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I am trying to **extract** few files contained in the java project into a certain path, lets say "c:\temp".
[image: eclipse]

I tried to use this example :

```
      String home = getClass().getProtectionDomain().
                    getCodeSource().getLocation().toString().
                    substring(6);
      JarFile jar = new JarFile(home);
      ZipEntry entry = jar.getEntry("mydb.mdb");
      File efile = new File(dest, entry.getName());

      InputStream in = 
         new BufferedInputStream(jar.getInputStream(entry));
      OutputStream out = 
         new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(efile));
      byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
      for (;;)  {
        int nBytes = in.read(buffer);
        if (nBytes <= 0) break;
        out.write(buffer, 0, nBytes);
      }
      out.flush();
      out.close();
      in.close();
```

I think I am doing it wrong and, this code probably looking for a specific jar but not in my project directory. I prefer to figure a way that can retrieve my files from resources package, inside the project folder and extract it to specific folder i choose.

I am using Eclipse, 1.4 J2SE library.

Comment: Please show your code. (Don't use links to external sites) Have you correctly esacped the \ character?

Comment: Does the exception mention which file isn't found?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's hard to guess what's wrong without any code examples.
But as for pair of random guesses I could tell that sometimes you get this kind of error when the file is locked by earlier instance of your program which is still running. Make sure you've got only one running instance of Eclipse.

Also you can try to refresh the project folder by right click --> refresh to sync your file system with Eclipse's internal file system: when it comes to Eclipse, multiple refresh/rebuild someway magically solves project problems :)

Comment: it's not the case in my opinion. i was trying to extract a file from my java eclipse project into c:/ . i seen few samples of people using bat file to cover this issue.

Comment: Show us the exact code snippet you're using + stacktrace instead of this example plz, cos I don't see neither the way you're declaring path to directory (so we've no idea is it correct) nor the line where exception is thrown

Comment: updated my question . you may want to reconsider your answer. thank you